# How to get the Gmail ID on clicking the link in the mail

Tags: java, gmail

i have a java application that sends group mail with a link (Only **Gmail**), i need to get the mailId of the person who clicks the link in the mail, and based on the mailId it should login to may application, is there any api for connecting, or what should i follow.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Gmail sanitisd the links as best as they can. You will have to generate unique link for each user and map that to gmail account in your database. For example, add a query parameter `id=12345` to your link like : http://yourdomain.com/app/?id=12345

Comment: @gigadot-thanks for the reply, here I need to send group mails, i cant create individual mails for each user. is there any possibility to get the mailid? ... like getting from cookies.

Comment: no, because of security reason. the whole web browser, http, etc., are built to prevent this.

Comment: if you can get cookies, then you can actually login to their site.